# SQL Server 2005 - Find Which Stored Procs Run To A Particular Table

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

- Is there a quick way that I can find
  which stored procedures run to a
  particular table in my database?
- The database is very large with lots of tables and SPROCS....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to restrict the search to stored procedures then you can do this:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'P'
    AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%name_of_your_table%'
ORDER BY name
```

If you wanted to include other SQL modules -- for examples, functions, triggers, views etc -- then  you could alter the query to do `WHERE type IN ('P', 'FN', 'IF', 'TF', 'V')` etc, or use the alternative given in [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361141/sql-server-2005-find-which-stored-procs-run-to-a-particular-table/3361180#3361180).

Answer (score 3):

A Combination of looking at dependencies and looking at the text of your objects should do it.

```
select * from sys.sql_modules
where 
definition like '%tableName%'
/*AND objectproperty(object_id,'isprocedure')=1 to just look at procedures*/

exec sp_depends 'tableName'
```