# SQL query to get Stored Procedure crop result if the routine_definition is greater than 4000 char

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this query to get all the stored procedure in my database (I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008):

```
 SELECT
     SPECIFIC_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
 FROM 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

For almost all result everything is ok, but for the row with a very long `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` the result is cropped.

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Which tool are you using when you execute the SELECT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try with `sp_helptext 'ProcedureName'` or you can use either `sys.sql_modules` or `OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id])` function to get the stored procedure text. 
All this gives your exact code. `Information_Schema.Routines` will give up to max of nvarchar(4000).

Comment: You are right. This link is very useful to complete the anwer: https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/08/t-sql-tuesday-24-dude-wheres-the-rest-of-my-procedure

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio then it is possible that it does not display all of the text of the stored procedure (since I believe [there is a 8192 character limit for each column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178782(v=sql.100))).

One thing you can do to check this is to verify the length of the string stored in the column:

```
SELECT
     SPECIFIC_NAME
   , ROUTINE_DEFINITION
   , LEN(ROUTINE_DEFINITION) [Length in characters]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

If this length is greater than 8192 then it is possible that the truncation occurs only on display level (SSMS) and not in the actual code of the stored procedure.

There is however a way to increase this number, as mentioned [**here** - Options (Query Results/SQL Server/Results to Grid Page)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190078(v=sql.100).aspx)

> To change the options for the current queries, click Query Options on
> the Query menu, or right-click in the SQL Server Query window and
> select Query Options.

...

> Maximum Characters Retrieved
>
> Non XML data: Enter a number from 1 through 65535 to specify the maximum number of characters that will be displayed in each cell.

Comment: I use a Python script to connect to my server. I noticed that the limit is 4000 char for the `Information_Schema.Routines`, probably I have to use an alternative way to get my SP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
     SPECIFIC_NAME, cast(ROUTINE_DEFINITION AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

Comment: How about cases when a procedure has 18k chars? VARCHAR(MAX) limited with 4k