# How to see what stored procs/functions/triggers rely on a column in a table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a specific column entry in an unknown table in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818598/find-a-specific-column-entry-in-an-unknown-table-in-a-database)
>   [how to search Sql Server 2008 R2 stored procedures for a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354256/how-to-search-sql-server-2008-r2-stored-procedures-for-a-string)

Hello I'm trying to figure out a fairly complex SQL Server(2008 in 2000 compatibility) database. There are 3 columns in a table I'm particularly concerned with. I've searched the code of our application and it seems to make no direct usage of these 3 columns but I know somewhere in the database they are populated and used. So it must be in triggers, functions, and/or stored procedures.

What is the best way of figuring out where to look for the code that populates these 3 columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to search Sql Server 2008 R2 stored procedures for a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354256/how-to-search-sql-server-2008-r2-stored-procedures-for-a-string) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991030/searching-in-sql-management-studio-2005/3991077#3991077 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361141/sql-server-2005-find-which-stored-procs-run-to-a-particular-table

Comment: Keep in mind it could also be populated by an SSIS package or SQL Agent job.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??